# Como retornar saldo automaticamente com AJAX sem post

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou tentando fazer uma função que retorne o resultado de uma expressão. Exemplo:

Quero fazer a distribuição de um valor informado pelos meses de um ano. Exemplo:

120.000 = Jan/10.000  Fev/10.000 etc.

Porém se o usuário alterar qualquer mês para mais ou para menos, o resultado do valor informado (120.000) subtraído da soma dos meses deve figurar no mês de Dezembro.

Com a ajuda do amigo Darlei, consegui iniciar este código

```js
function saldo()
{
 var total = document.getElementById("total");
 var jan = document.getElementById("jan");
 var fev = document.getElementById("fev");
 var mar = document.getElementById("mar");
 var abr = document.getElementById("abr");
 var mai = document.getElementById("mai");
 var jun = document.getElementById("jun");
 var jul = document.getElementById("jul");
 var ago = document.getElementById("ago");
 var set = document.getElementById("set");
 var out = document.getElementById("out");
 var nov = document.getElementById("nov");
 var dez = document.getElementById("dez");

 dez.value = total.value - jan.value - fev.value - mar.value - abr.value - mai.value - jun.value - jul.value - ago.value - set.value - out.value - nov.value;

}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label for="total">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="120.000" />

    <label for="jan">Jan</label>
    <input type="text" name="jan" id="jan" />
     <label for="textfield">Fev</label>
    <input type="text" name="fev" id="fev" />
     <label for="textfield">Mar</label>
    <input type="text" name="mar" id="mar" />
     <label for="textfield">Abr</label>
    <input type="text" name="abr" id="abr" />
     <label for="textfield">Mai</label>
    <input type="text" name="mai" id="mai" />
     <label for="textfield">Jun</label>
    <input type="text" name="jun" id="jun" />
     <label for="textfield">Jul</label>
    <input type="text" name="jul" id="jul" />
     <label for="textfield">Ago</label>
    <input type="text" name="ago" id="ago" />
     <label for="textfield">Set</label>
    <input type="text" name="set" id="set" />
     <label for="textfield">Out</label>
    <input type="text" name="out" id="out" />
     <label for="textfield">Nov</label>
    <input type="text" name="nov" id="nov" />
     <label for="textfield">Dez</label>
    <input type="text" name="dez" id="dez" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Mas ainda não sei como retornar este valor para o INPUT

Comment: Você tem todos valores em inputs? Como eles são carregados/inseridos na página? Se for somente fazer/mostrar o calculo, poderia fazer um js mais simples, ajax somente se precisar gravar os valores no banco ou retornar algum valor de lá, seria esse o caso?

Comment: Não precisa gravar esses valores não. Eles vêm de um form e serão exibidos após a inserção no banco. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Caso o usuário aumente o valor de um mês, a subtração será negativa porque a soma dos meses será maior que 120.000

Comment: Exatamente isso que , eu gostaria de evidenciar. A hipossuficiência e a hiperssuficiência

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma de trabalhar com os campos é adicionar uma `class` em cada um, pois assim fica mais fácil e deixa o código mais enxuto. Eu adicionei `class="meses"` em cada campo dos meses.

Veja se o resultado é o esperado:

```js
window.onload = function(){
   var meses = document.getElementsByClassName("meses");  
   var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value.replace('.',''));
   
   function reCalc(){
      var soma = 0;
      for(var x=0; x<meses.length-1; x++){
         soma += parseFloat(meses[x].value);
      }
      meses[meses.length-1].value= valor-soma;
   }
   
   function divisao(i){
      var divisao = valor / 12;

      for(var x=0; x<meses.length; x++){
         meses[x].value = divisao;
         
         if(!i){
            meses[x].addEventListener("input", reCalc );
         }
      }
   }
   
   divisao();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label for="total">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="120.000" />

    <label for="jan">Jan</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="jan" id="jan" />
     <label for="textfield">Fev</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="fev" id="fev" />
     <label for="textfield">Mar</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="mar" id="mar" />
     <label for="textfield">Abr</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="abr" id="abr" />
     <label for="textfield">Mai</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="mai" id="mai" />
     <label for="textfield">Jun</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="jun" id="jun" />
     <label for="textfield">Jul</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="jul" id="jul" />
     <label for="textfield">Ago</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="ago" id="ago" />
     <label for="textfield">Set</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="set" id="set" />
     <label for="textfield">Out</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="out" id="out" />
     <label for="textfield">Nov</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="nov" id="nov" />
     <label for="textfield">Dez</label>
    <input class="meses" type="text" name="dez" id="dez" />
  </p>
</form>
```